In Python, how to print a date in an array concisely without extracting it?
When I extract a date from a PR and printed it as below
updated = pull_request.updated_at
print(f"Updated At: {updated}")

It printed well
Updated At: 2024-05-09 00:45:14+00:00

However if I put in an array (I have some other element in the array, but for simplicity purpose, I just show I have the date)
updated = pull_request.updated_at
pull_requests.append([updated])

for pull_request in pull_requests:
  print(pull_request)


It printed as below format
[datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 9, 6, 7, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]

How can I have the date variable in the array, and get the array printed directly i.e. print(pull_request), while still having the date string shown concisely, like the 2024-05-09 00:45:14+00:00 format?
p/s: I can do it by extracting the element in the array to print print(pull_request[0]), but it will be cumbersome given I actually have several element in the array, and I don't want to extract them out individually.
updated = pull_request.updated_at
pull_requests.append([updated])
for pull_request in pull_requests:
  print(pull_request[0])


Well, you’re getting a list representation. Note that [2024-05-09 …] would be an invalid list representation. At best ['2024-05-09 …'] would be valid. If you want that, you need to explicitly cast your date to a str().

BTW, this question could be simplified to just something like foo = [updated, 'bar', 42]; print(foo). That appending and looping is irrelevant and confusing at best.

In your second code fragment you are printing a list in which case the individual elements are represented by the return value from the element's __repr__ implementation

You may be able to get away with just map(str, collection) (and then either making this a list() or iterating over your collection)
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 9, 6, 7, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> print(d)  # uses str()
2024-05-09 06:07:36+00:00
>>> [d]       # uses repr()
[datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 9, 6, 7, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]
>>> str(d)
'2024-05-09 06:07:36+00:00'
>>> repr(d)
'datetime.datetime(2024, 5, 9, 6, 7, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)'

map() over collection
>>> list(map(str, [d, d]))  # list pops map generator
['2024-05-09 06:07:36+00:00', '2024-05-09 06:07:36+00:00']

However, you may really want to make some custom class which can hold the pull request instance and make it nicer to deal with (for example printing a block of information at once in addition to the date, some .to_json() method, .__lt__() to sort by updated/merged/whatever, etc.)
Here with a multiline string if you have a lot to write, but I can't really recommend it
import textwrap
class PullRequest:
    def __init__(self, pr):
        self.pr = pr
    def __str__(self):
        return textwrap.dedent(f"""
        Updated At: {self.pr.updated_at}
        Last Author {}
        ...
        """).lstrip()
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({str(self)})"
    def __lt__(self, other):  # allows sorting (maybe useless here)
        return self.pr.updated_at < other.pr.updated_at


Since it is a datetime.datetime instance, you can do pull_requests.append([updated.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')])

Or just str(updated). But then it’s not a datetime anymore…

we have to format the date before appending it to the array.
Try this:
updated = pull_request.updated_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
